# Алгоритм расположения картинок на координатной сетке

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть исходные картинки. Разрешение `3000*3000`. Есть холст размером `2500*2500`. Выбираем количество строк и колонок. Допустим 4*4. В общем `16` изображений.

Исходные картинки ресайзим на -70%. На выходе текст

```
x="0" y="0"/>
x="750" y="0"/>
x="1500" y="0"/>
x="2250" y="0"/>
x="0" y="-750"/>
x="750" y="-750"/>
x="1500" y="-750"/>
x="2250" y="-750"/>
x="0" y="-1500"/>
x="750" y="-1500"/>
x="1500" y="-1500"/>
x="2250" y="-1500"/>
x="0" y="-2250"/>
x="750" y="-2250"/>
x="1500" y="-2250"/>
x="2250" y="-2250"/>
```

Это я сделал вручную. Вопрос как перевести в алгоритм эту координатную сетку

update

```
var rows = 4;
var cols = 3;

var ii = 3000 / rows;
var jj = 3000 / cols;



var lst = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        var str = $"x=\"{j*jj}\" y=\"{i*-ii}\"/>";
        lst.Add(str);
    }

}
```

Сделал вот так. В принципе для 4*4 работает. Вот только как быть если у меня 4*3?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну вот у вас шаг по ширине = ширина / количество шагов. То же самое по длине. Тогда вам надо 2 цикла, один вложенный в другой, где пороходить по ширине и длине с посчитанными шагами.

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, так и сделал. А как вычислить длину-ширину кубика? Допустим у нас 4 на 3. Ширина холста - 3000*3000.

Comment: @tym32167 дополнил

Comment: Ну у вас ширина 3000, вам надо разбить на 4 квадрата. Делим 3000 на 4, получаем сторону квадрата 750.

Comment: это я сделал... см ниже дополнение

Comment: `Вот только как быть если у меня 4*3?` не понял, какие с этим проблемы? Формулы те же самые, циклы те же самые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Дано:
1. холст размером 2500*2500
2. картинки размером 3000*3000 (квадратные) 

Задача: разместить картинки в сетке MxN (M строк, N столбцов) "без зазоров" между картинками.

Решение:


int cellWidth = 2500 / N;  // ширина ячейки
int cellHeight = 2500 / M; // высота ячейки

// Минимальная из сторон ячейки
int minDimention = min(cellWidth, cellHeight); 

// Коэффициент сжатия исходной картинки, чтобы уместить ее в ячейку, сохранив пропорции.
// (ширина картинки после ресайза на этот фактор станет равна minDimention, 
// ей же будет равна и высота, т.к. картинки квадратные).
float scaleFactor = minDimention / 3000; // у вас в примере это 0.3 (-70% = 1 - 0.7 = 0.3)

for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) // по строкам
{
    for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) // по столбцам
    {
        int cellStartX = j * cellWidth;
        int cellStartY = -i * cellHeight; // у вас 'y' уходит в отрицательную оболать с ростом номера ряда, поэтому тут минус.

        // Верхний левый угол картинки будет иметь координаты
        int imageX = cellStartX + (cellWidth - minDimention) / 2;
        int imageY = cellStartY - (cellHeight - minDimention) / 2;

    }

}
```